# Probability that two slices of cake have an equal number of raisins

Tags: probability, binomial-coefficients, binomial-distribution

> You, your parents, your sister, go to visit grandma for her birthday. Grandma made a cake for the party. If she puts $20$ raisins in the cake at random in the cake, and she divides the cake into $5$ equal pieces, what's the probability that your sister gets as many raisins as you?

Let $X$ be the number of raisins in your piece. Let $Y$ be the number of raisins in her piece.

> Since there are not that many raisins, you can just go through all the possible numbers of raisins that both you and your sister would get :
>   $P(X=Y)=\Sigma_{k=0}^{10}P(X=Y=k)=\Sigma_{k=0}^{10}\binom{20}{k}\binom{20-k}{k}0.2^{2k}0.6^{20-2k}$ which is about $0.1406$.

$P[S_n=k|\theta]=$ $ n \choose k$ $\theta^k (1-\theta)^{n-k}$

where $S_n=X_1+X_2+...+X_n$ and $S_n \sim Bin(n,\theta)$

1.I don't understand why

> $P(X=Y)=\Sigma_{k=0}^{10}P(X=Y=k)=\Sigma_{k=0}^{10}\binom{20}{k}\binom{20-k}{k}0.2^{2k}0.6^{20-2k}$

Shouldn't it be

> $P(X=Y)=\Sigma_{k=0}^{10}P(X=Y=k)=\Sigma_{k=0}^{10}\binom{20}{k}\binom{20-k}{k}0.2^{2k}0.8^{20-2k}$?

2.I also don't understand why we have a product of binomial coefficients

$\binom{20}{k}\binom{20-k}{k}$. rather than one binomial coefficient either $\binom{20}{k}$ or $\binom{20-k}{k}$.

3.I also don't understand why we have exponentiation to the power of $2k$ and $20-2k$ rather than $k$ and $20-k$.

Would someone explain?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. There's an equal chance for each piece to have a given raisin. So each raisin has a $0.2$ chance to end up on your cake and likewise $0.2$ chance to end up on your sisters. This means that there's a $0.6$ chance it ends up on someone else's cake. So for the inside of the sum we will have $0.2^k (0.2)^k (0.6)^{20-k - k}$ which by algebra simplifies to $0.2^{2k} (0.6)^{20-2k}$
2. We have a product of binomials because we have to choose twice. Once for the number of ways to choose exactly $k$ raisins out of $20$ for your cake, and another to choose exactly $k$ raisins from the remaining $20 - k$ raisins for your sisters cake.
3. See my answer for number one, as this pretty much addresses this.